# Else statement did not get executed

Tags: python, if-statement, io, priority-queue

I have a text file that reads. I managed to get everything sorted but what I don't understand is that my code did not get executed in the else statement. (The Else statement will skip the useless data and will not add to the PriorityQueue.)

> id_is_g0000515
>
> num_is_0.92
>
> id_is_g0000774
>
> uselessdata2
>
> num_is_1.04
>
> hithere
>
> id_is_g0000377
>
> num_is_1.01
>
> pt21
>
> id_is_g0000521
>
> num_is_5.6

```
import os, sys, shutil, re


def readFile():
    from queue import PriorityQueue
    str1 = 'ID_IS'
    str2 = 'NUM_IS'
    q = PriorityQueue()
    #try block will execute if the text file is found
    try:
        fileName= open("Real_format.txt",'r')
        for line in fileName:
                for string in line.strip().split(','):
                    if string.find(str1): #if str1 is found
                        q.put(string[-4:]) #store it in PQ
                    elif string.find(str2):#if str2 is found
                        q.put(string[-8:]) #store it in PQ
                    else:
                        line.next() #skip the useless string
                        #q.remove(string)

        fileName.close() #close the file after reading          
        print("Displaying Sorted Data")
        #print("ID TYPE       Type")
        while not q.empty():
            print(q.get())

            #catch block will execute if no text file is found
    except IOError:
                print("Error: FileNotFoundException")
                return

readFile()
```

Comment: There is no `line.skip()` method; just drop the whole `else` block, you ignore lines by just.. moving on to the next line.

Comment: I tried its still reading the jibberish. Its still added to the priority queue

Comment: Those lines then contain one of your two strings.

Comment: I'm curious as to what made you try `line.skip()`.

Comment: sorry was a mistake.. I meant to put line.next()

Comment: That's just as puzzling.

Comment: I am curious why did the else condition did not get executed. It works perfectly on the if and else if statement.

Comment: the else condition is so that it skips the useless data by not adding it to the PQ. Even after removing the else statement, Its still reading the useless data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` doesn't do what you think it does. It returns the index of the string being sought or -1 if no string is found. In an `if` statement, all integers besides `0` are "truthy" (for instance, `bool(-1) is True and bool(0) is False and bool(1) is True`). Since none of the strings contain 'ID_IS', `string.find(str1)` is always -1 which is true... so the first `if` hits and the string is added to the queue.

You should convert strings to upper case for the comparison and use `startswith` instead of `find`.

```
import os, sys, shutil, re


def readFile():
    from queue import PriorityQueue
    str1 = 'ID_IS'
    str2 = 'NUM_IS'
    q = PriorityQueue()
    #try block will execute if the text file is found
    try:
        fileName= open("Real_format.txt",'r')
        for line in fileName:
                # from the sample text, the split is pointless but harmless
                for string in line.strip().split(','):
                    if string.upper().startswith(str1): #if str1 is found
                        q.put(string[-4:]) #store it in PQ
                    elif string.upper().startswith(str2):#if str2 is found
                        q.put(string[-8:]) #store it in PQ

        fileName.close() #close the file after reading          
        print("Displaying Sorted Data")
        #print("ID TYPE       Type")
        while not q.empty():
            print(q.get())

            #catch block will execute if no text file is found
    except IOError:
                print("Error: FileNotFoundException")
                return

readFile()
```

Comment: No wonder mine is giving weird outputs. It all starts with the .find() Thank you so much.